# populate mongoose without ref as parent of populated object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm doing a populate on, imagine this mongoose collection:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    lists: [
        _id: {
            type: String,
            ref: List
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I do a `populate` on user model, and then as a resulat, I get this:

```
lists: [{
    _id: {
        _id:"rJ5izylbG"
        ...
    }
}]
```

I don't want the first `_id:` and I want it to be just an array of objects. like this:

```
lists: [
    {
        _id:"rJ5izylbG"
        ...
    }
]
```

How can I achieve that with mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
lists: [
    {
        type:  Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: List
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm using a plugin for IDs, so I'm setting it so String. it doesn't matter after all.